# FailedLimitProcessingTime; access to Forge Journal file possible?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

We have a Revit model that doesn't seem to be running in Forge. It runs just fine in our local Revit Plugin, but it seems to 'hang' when trying it in Forge. After 3 hours, Forge just times-out...

The model isn't that big (less than 150MB), and we've handled many different (and larger) models before with success.

The logs from Forge doesn't tell us that much. It seems that the code from out plugin did not even run (we log the start of our code). Is there a way to get access to the journal file from Forge? Or is there an other way to see what might be the cause?

```
...
[05/03/2021 14:32:10] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild) 21.1.20.44 (VersionNumber) 2021 (SubVersionNumber) 2021.2
[05/03/2021 17:31:52] Error: Revit Core Engine Core Console is shut down due to process time limit.
[05/03/2021 17:31:52] End script phase.
[05/03/2021 17:31:52] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[05/03/2021 17:31:52] Job finished with result FailedLimitProcessingTime
```

Comment: Could you provide workitem id for the job? Is it consistently reproducible with this model? Do other models work fine for the same activity?

Answer (score 0):

the workitemid:b27223519e824cdc90df80a1af6e718b

The issue is reproducible. So if you like we can send the model again and it will do exactly the same.

Comment: Hi @Daniel - I looked at the logs for `b27223519e824cdc90df80a1af6e718b` and did not find any thing obvious. Is there a way you can help us with a minimal reproducible sample? If the input file is not sensitive could you share it with `forge.help`[at]`autodesk.com` and refer both the stack overflow posts you made?